# creating a table in mysql using pymysql and sqlalchemy

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I have a problem with creating a table in mysql using python 3.3.
I'm using Pymysql-0.15 and SQLAlchemy.

currently I'm running this code in Pythonwin and have the following output.

```
from sqlalchemy imort *

    from sqlalchemy import *
    import pymysql
    engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://admin:admin@127.0.0.1/dbeerste")

    engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://admin:admin@127.0.0.1/dbeerste")
    metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
    users_table = Table('users', metadata, Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True), Column('name', String(40)), Column('age', Integer), Column('password', String),)
    metadata.create_all(engine)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\schema.py", line 2740, in create_all
    tables=tables)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1489, in _run_visitor
    conn._run_visitor(visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1132, in _run_visitor
    **kwargs).traverse_single(element)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py", line 109, in traverse_single
    return meth(obj, **kw)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\ddl.py", line 56, in visit_metadata
    collection = [t for t in sql_util.sort_tables(tables)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\ddl.py", line 57, in <listcomp>
    if self._can_create_table(t)]
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\ddl.py", line 35, in _can_create_table
    table.name, schema=table.schema)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\dialects\mysql\base.py", line 2039, in has_table
    rs = connection.execute(st)
 File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 664, in execute
    params)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 808, in _execute_text
    statement, parameters
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 878, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1036, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    from e
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) (1146, "#42S02Table 'dbeerste.users' doesn't exist") b'DESCRIBE `users`' ()
```

Can annyone help me with this problem please ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks right, but MySQL requires that you specify a length for the password field. After fixing that, I was able to execute your query against a MySQL database no problem. If it still doesn't work for you, then it's a problem with either your database server or driver, so you could try reinstalling these things.

Comment: We also tried that, but we came across the same error.
The thing is we are able to insert into the database with our mysqlconector conectionstring but we'd like to use pymysql.
engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://admin:admin@127.0.0.1/dbeerste")
thanks for your quick respons :)